# How Do I Film A Rotating Object With White Background?

Tags: editing, chromakey

I often need to rotate object when making video and rotating with hands is not convenient. I wish there was a helping rotational hand spehere that would rotate as i film object where i could set rotational angles and in the end get to see an object with white background as it rotates. I want to place smartphone instead of that globus in the middle:

[image]

People suggested to do it with chromakey in software without studio or special equipment but it will take a learning curve and time to get familiarized with basics.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [a revolving cake stand](http://bakingbites.com/2008/06/choosing-a-revolving-cake-stand/).

Comment: Thats the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to rotate large objects, you could try a [Lazy Susan](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Lazy_Susan)